# jQuery validate, element.value is undefined in errorplacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I´ve try to build a validate for my registerform. I´m using jQuery validate. When the textbox is empty I want the errormessage to show up as my placeholder. When the text is added but stills throws a error I want to use custom settings.

My problem is when debug this code:

```
.validate({
    debug: true,
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.value === "") {
            element.attr("placeholder", error.text());
        }
        else {
            alert(element.value);
        }
    }
});
```

I´m getting undefined on elment.value. According to Devtools element.value is the text in the textbox (changes when text is added in the textbox) but it´s also says it´s undefined when I watch the value as the red circle to the left.

[image]

I´m using MVC helpers for the textbox form:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SurName, new { @class = "form-control required", placeholder = "Förnamn", @type = "SurName" })
```

I´m I using wrong value or attr?

Comment: What is `@type = "SurName"`? That's not a valid `type` attribute

Comment: SurName comes from my ViewModel where it has a corresponding  Column. Like this: [Column("SurName")]. It´s makes the autofill work properly in the browser for me.

Comment: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) is the list of valid `type` attributes - or did you mean `id = "SurName"`?

Comment: I used a guide that showed how I can create custom types with Columns. I can´t find it at the moment but it solved my problem with setting the right value to autofill. Has that anything to do with my JavaScript problem?

Comment: I don't know. I just raised it because it's invalid html. But looking at you screen shot (RHS) it actually shows `type="text"` anyway.

Comment: Give us jsFiddle link .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `element.value` is undefined in `errorPlacement`

You are breaking it by using `value`, which is undefined and not a valid argument for this function.  Only `error` and `element` have been defined as the two arguments for your `errorPlacement` function.  Instead, use jQuery `val()` to get the value of the element.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (element.val() === "") {
        element.attr("placeholder", error.text());
    }
    else {
        // alert(element.val()); // <- Safari fail
        console.log(element.val());
    }
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/atrL0h1s/**

---

However, I would never use an `alert()` since you can do much nicer looking things using jQuery.  In this case, dismissing the `alert()` causes a new alert to appear over and over, in an infinite loop, when using Safari.

Comment: Thanks alot Sparky! I will try to switch value to val() and hope for the best. Btw the alertbox was just for testing, I´m thinking about using toasters to show value. Anyway thank you for your respond. I get back to you and let you know if it works.